# Domain name and server mapping

Tags: dns, domain-name

I recently bought a Domain name from Freenom (eg, `mysitename.tk` ) .
I also have a server running in my house that I can access via the internet (e.g. `1.2.3.4:9090` -( I have a fixed IP connection from my ISP- ) ) .

Currently ,When I am accessing a service of this server , I have to type - `1.2.3.4:9090/MobileStore` to go the website .
( I deploy war files on this linux machine) .

Now , I want to bind the domain name with the server  i.e., I want to access it like ( `mysitename.tk/MobileStore` or just `mysitename.tk` ).

What is the process to bind domain name to server .

Answer (score 2):

## A Record

You need an A record at your NS. The A record should point to the IP address you have listed.

### CNAME

You can then set for any subdomains you would like to point to your site (ie. 'WWW', 'Mail', etc.) Those subdomains CNAME records can point to '@' and it will point to your base A Record.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `URL Forwarding` from the domain's `Management Tools` area, like this:

```
URL Forwarding
    http://1.2.3.4:9090/MobileStore

Forward mode
    Frame
```

This will forward `mysitename.tk` to `http://1.2.3.4:9090/MobileStore` and the address in the `Address bar` of the browser will remain `mysitename.tk`

Comment: That method isn't supported by all nameserver hosters. I would recommend setting an A Record with the IP as target.

Comment: But that will not point to the port and the directory. As for the URL Forwarding it is supported by `Freenom` and since CamundaGuy doesn't say that the DNS is somewhere else I assume it's there.